# Receiving POST from individual forms and adding to seperate Session Array

Tags: php

I have several stages to an application process consisting of multiple forms on different pages.

I have created a session to handle the data.

My question is, without explicitly stipulating every form field form can i add the form post to an individual part of the session array one by one.

So that when im at the end i can just loop through and print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you could do something like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    $_SESSION['form'][$key] = $value;
```

This will save all the POST data into the `$_SESSION['form']` array. Note that it saves all the data, a malicious user can just add values to this.

On the last page you can echo the fields like this (don't forget to escape the values, that's what `htmlspecialchars()` is for).

```
foreach($_SESSION['form'] as $key => $value)
    echo htmlspecialchars($key) . ": " . htmlspecialchars($value) . "<br />\n";
```

Edit: The `array_merge()` approach is acutaly more elegant than this one, so just forget about the first piece of code.

Comment: So i could just post this on every page with the respective $_SESSION['form'] changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear but I think you're saying you want a single array of all your form variables from each page. Something like this should do the trick:

```
if( !isset($_SESSION['form_data']) ) { 
     $_SESSION['form_data'] = array();
}
$_SESSION['form_data'] = array_merge($_SESSION['form_data'], $_POST );
```

You would put that as the code to handle the submit on each page and then of course the last page you could loop through `$_SESSION['form_data']`

Note that any form fields having the same name will get overwritten each time they are used. So if you had `name` on page 1 and `name` on page 2. The value of `name` from page 2 would end up in the array

For security though you should check your input data even before putting it into the session.